# Python win32com SaveAs2 error when I try to save file

Tags: python, win32com

```
def convert_to_word():
    target = pwd + "/open.doc"
    source = pwd + "/template.html"

    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()

    # try:
    app.Documents.Open(source)
    app.Documents.SaveAs2(target,FileFormat=0)
    app.Documents.Open(source)
    app.Selection.WholeStory()
    app.Selection.Fields.Unlink()
    app.Documents.Save()

    # except Exception as e:
    #     print(e)
    # finally:
    app.ActiveDocument.Close()
```

I need to save html file to .doc, but it report a error `<unknown>.SaveAs2` which I cant solve.

Can anyone help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My first answer on stackoverflow ...
I had had same troubles then I have found solution:

Your code seems to be almost OK. You just need to store your opened document to a variable and then use SaveAs2 function on the variable.

```
my_doc = app.Documents.Open(source)
my_doc.SaveAs2(target, FileFormat=0)
```